# Почему не работают два оператора в lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

defaults_commands = {
    'help': lambda: print('text'),
    'shut up':  lambda: print('\n Exiting...') sys.exit()
}
```

File "ToDoList.py", line 8
    }
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: я хочу чтоб при вводе шат ап выводилось сообщение и затем выполнялась команда sys exit

Comment: Потому что два statement подряд через пробел в лямбде писать никто никогда не разрешал. Сделайте обычную функцию и пишите в ней что угодно, лямбда здесь ни к чему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вроде работает. В Питоне можно через запятую команды писать. А чтобы всё в одну лямбду попало надо в скобки взять. Ну или по факту tuple тут получается, лень уже разбираться.

```
defaults_commands = {
    'help': lambda: print('text'),
    'shut up':  lambda: (print('\n Exiting...'), sys.exit())
}
```

Comment: Я так пробовал только скобку перед лябдой писал) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

- Во-первых, предполагаю, что часть кода будет ругать синтакс при котором **lambda** пытается использовать **print**
- Во-вторых, **sys.exit()** следует вынести за фигурные скобки.

Предполагаю, что для задачи, которую Вы пытаетесь решить данный комментарий может быть лишним, потому предлагаю lambda-функции переопределить на обычные.

Пример:

```
import sys


def help_function(text):
    print(text)


def exit_function(text):
    print(text)
    sys.exit()


defaults_commands = {
    'help': help_function('text'),
    'shut up': exit_function('\n Exiting...'), 
    # Внимание! Код после вызова sys.exit() 
    # в функции exit_function работать НЕ БУДЕТ! 
    # Python завершил свою работу и дальше код НЕ ЧИТАЕТ.
    'show me': help_function('Show me please!')
}

# Внимание! Код ниже работать НЕ БУДЕТ!
print('example text')
```

В данном примере надо понимать, что при присвоении какой-либо функции к элементу массива **defaults_commands** - функции будут вызваны автоматически (то бишь сработает вызов и они отработают свой код).

По-этому Ваш скрип выполнится не полностью и завершит свою работу.

Comment: "Во-первых" - нет, никто не запрещает использовать print внутри lambda-выражения. Но в целом - да, нужно использовать обычные функции. Во-вторых - в вашем коде стоит обернуть вызовы функций внутри словаря в лямбды, тогда все будет работать (функции будут вызваны когда нам нужно, а не в момент создания словаря).